# Android ImageView margins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Creating layout and can not solve margins up and above the ImageView
(and don't understand why they appear).
Logo itself is without these margins.
I use layout_width="250dp" the same as for the buttons.
And layout_height="wrap content".

[image]

Layout code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/game_logo"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        style="@style/menuButtonStyle"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/result_button"
        style="@style/menuButtonStyle"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/high_score" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        style="@style/menuButtonStyle"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/settings" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_button"
        style="@style/menuButtonStyle"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/about_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can I manage this without setting ImageView's layout_height in dp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set following property in your `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```